# How to use ApacheDS as LDAP backend with BIND9 or other

Tags: dns-hosting, apache-ds

After long time passed on the web looking for a way to use ApacheDS as backend LDAP with BIND9, I found nothing about this subject, so I ask here.

I am preparing setup of the infrastructure of my company, which will be entirely hosted on Linux CentOS 7 for a matter of costs.

I first tried OpenLDAP and FreeIPA but ApacheDS was the one I decided to use as LDAP server.

Problem is, I need to setup DNS server too, in order to resolve and forward DNS requests from other clients. I installed BIND9 because it seems to be the most popular one. I want to register DNS entries into LDAP instead of named.conf file because it is not convenient. I found a tutorial who explains how to configure named.conf for use LDAP but it seems LDAP Attributes and Objects BIND9 is using is not compatible with ApacheDS's one.

Can someone help me to resolve this problem ? Is there a way ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a directory server does not yet support particular attribute types you'll need to [*"extend the schema"*](https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/2.3.1-adding-schema-elements.html) , i.e. add the attribute definitions to the directory server.

The attribute definitions required for and used by the dynamic LDAP back-end plug-in for BIND are found in the documentation:  https://pagure.io/bind-dyndb-ldap/blob/master/f/doc/schema.ldif

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was able to convert and import schema from link you gave to me. It seems ApacheDS does not permit the import of schema.ldif as its actual state, needed to modify syntax.